Is it possible to prove that $\mathcal{l}^2$ is a Hilbert space using the Riesz-Fisher theorem?
The space $\mathcal{l}^2$ of sequences of summable squares is famously known to be a Hilbert space when given the scalar product:
$$\langle (u_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}},(v_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \rangle:= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}u_nv_n$$
The proof I know of this fact is an elemental proof which goal is the very definition of completeness to show that $\mathcal{l}^2$ with given metric by the scalar product above is indeed complete, using Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, series convergence and the very definition of $\mathcal{l}^2$.
I wondered if another proof using more advanced results could be done shorter. Specifically I was wondering if the Riesz-Fisher theorem could be used to prove the completeness assuming that at least one infinite dimensional Hilbert space exists, so that we have (by Riesz-Fisher) $\Delta:H\rightarrow \mathcal{l}^2$ surjective, linear and continous.
Note: The Riesz-Fisher theorem stated that if $\{u_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ was an ortonormal system of $H$ a Hilbert space, then the map $\Delta:H\rightarrow \mathcal{l}^2$ defined by $\Delta(x)=(\langle x, u_i\rangle)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ was well defined, was surjective, linear and continous.

If you know that $L^2(X, \mu)$ is complete for a measure space $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ (this is the Fischer-Riesz-Thm. that I know), you can set $X = \mathbb{N}$, $\Sigma = 2^X$ and $\mu$ the counting measure to get $\ell^2$.

I mean, is the image of a complete space through a linear continous function also complete?

Yes, quotients of Hilbert spaces (or, more generally, Banach or Fréchet spaces) are complete.

@Jochen: How do you define the metric on the quotient?

For a normed space $(X,|\cdot|)$, a closed subspace $L$ of $X$ and the linear quotient map $q:X\to X/L$, the quotient norm on $X/L$ is $|q(x)|_{\sim}=\inf{|y|: q(x)=q(y)}$.

@Jochen Could you please explain a bit more? I did not know the concept of Hilbert spaces quotient.

@IAG, its your standard quotient of vector spaces with the norm described above by Jochen.

@Jochen : I believe this is true only when you do a quotient by a closed subspace.
